# Seaborn clustermap colorbar adjustment

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Having several issues adjusting the colorbar in `seaborn.clustermap`. I'm trying to:

1. orient the colorbar horizontally
2. change the colorbar border color
3. change the colorbar tick length

I've checked the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) for `figure.colorbar` to no avail.

Minimal code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data
corr = np.corrcoef(np.random.randn(10, 200))

#clustermap
kws = dict(cbar_kws=dict(label='Label', ticks=[0,0.50,1], orientation='horizontal'), figsize=(6, 6))
sns.clustermap(corr, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, **kws)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can grab the subplot with the colorbar via `g.ax_cbar`. Then you can change its position, title, spines and tick lengths:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

corr = np.corrcoef(np.random.randn(10, 200))

kws = dict(cbar_kws=dict(ticks=[0, 0.50, 1], orientation='horizontal'), figsize=(6, 6))
g = sns.clustermap(corr, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, **kws)
x0, _y0, _w, _h = g.cbar_pos
g.ax_cbar.set_position([x0, 0.9, g.ax_row_dendrogram.get_position().width, 0.02])
g.ax_cbar.set_title('colorbar title')
g.ax_cbar.tick_params(axis='x', length=10)
for spine in g.ax_cbar.spines:
    g.ax_cbar.spines[spine].set_color('crimson')
    g.ax_cbar.spines[spine].set_linewidth(2)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.clustermap with customized colorbar]

Comment: Some of these things might indeed need to be done post-hoc, but you can set the cbar position while drawing with the `cbar_pos` kwarg.